# How to detect if class is injectable

Tags: java, reflection

I am using Java Reflection to initialize different types of objects.  All of these objects are constructed the same way (namely, I pass in the same values to construct them).

Thus, my injector looks through each of the fields, and does a long if/else statement like the following:

```
if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
   return new Foo(values);
else if (Bar.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
   return new Bar(values);
else if...//Continue over and over
```

I can't define an interface that requires the class to have a factory, because factories are static by nature.  The same holds true for extending an abstract class.

Is there some way I can remove the above if/else statement so my injecting class has no idea about the classes that need injecting (besides the fact that it can be constructed with `values`?

Comment: Have you looked at the Spring source code? This is a problem that has already been solved by an existing open source project and you can just fork the code and re-use it.

Comment: Yes, I actually use Spring.  I never even thought to use it in this situation.  This is actually what I'm looking for.  Post an answer and I'll accept it @mttdbrd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

Have you looked at the Spring source code? This is a problem that has already been solved by an existing open source project and you can just fork the code and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like (untested):

```
private <T> T newInstance(Class<T> type){
    Constructor<T> constructor = type.getConstructor(valueTypes);
    return constructor.newInstance(values)
}
```

Then call:

```
Object obj = newInstance(field.getType());
```

where valueTypes are the types of the values.